# Can I present numbers from numbers from 0 to 255 in less than 8 bits?

Tags: binary, compression, coordinates, binary-data, coordinate-systems

I know that it takes 8 bits to demonstrate a number like 255 in binary system. I'm desperately looking for a way of storing numbers from 0 to 255 (especially from 90 to 255) in less than 8 bits. Anything can be helpful, like coordinate systems, spirals, compressions, etc.

I need to store a number up to 255 in less than 8 bits (1 byte).

Answer (score 1):

No, not all of them.

You can represent *some* of them in less than eight bits, and *others* in more than eight bits. Such a representation could result in an overall compression, if the frequency of occurrence of the byte values is heavily biased in the direction of the ones represented with fewer bits.

Your "especially from 90 to 255" sounds like a small bias. If you could assure that *only* those values are present, then they could be represented in a little less than 7.38 bits each, on average.

Comment: Thank you for these useful information. I have two questions regarding your comments: 1- How can I show numbers from 90 to 255 in 7.38 bits? 2- Is it possible to write binary in a way that it would consist of 3-bit, 4-bit, 5-bit, 6-bit, 7-bit, and 8-bit bytes or arrays all in the same place? For example, writing 4 bit as a number, then following with 7 bit as another number, and then a 5-bit number.

Comment: Yes. You just treat the stream of bytes instead as a stream of bits.

Comment: It's great then. I tried to find something about it on Internet, but I couldn't exactly understand it. Is there any links you can suggest me about treating the stream of bytes please?